# Declare function and call it on jquery event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, organization

I saw, some days ago, an alternate way to use functions on jQuery event bindings. It consists on: first declare the function, and then call it on the binding, like as follows. I think the code remains better organized.

```
//Função para capturar e passar os elementos para a função de apply.
function invokeSequentialFade(){
    //code...
};

//Função para Instanciar o carousel de acordo com o dispositivo.
function invokeCarousel(){
    //code...
};

//Função para instanciar o scrollfade (elementos surgirem no scroll).
function invokeScrollFade(){
    //code..
};

//Fixando a navbar no topo, caso o usuário não esteja na Home.
function manipulateFixedNavbar(){
    //code...
};

/************ END - Declaração de funções ***********/

$(window).on("resize",invokeCarousel);
$(window).on("resize",manipulateFixedNavbar);
$(window).on("resize",invokeSequentialFade);
$(document).on("scroll",invokeScrollFade);
```

I haven't found any article explaining if this is a good practice.

My doubt is: can this wreak havoc? I also have AJAX loaded content in my page, so I don't know if this method does affect the application in any sort of situation.

Comment: Make your code cleaner by removing the body of the functions, which aren't necessary to show your example. That way we don't have to scroll to get to the binding portion. Example: `function invokeCarousel(){ ... }`

Comment: Nice one @HanletEscaño. Just edited it! Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks for the adjustment. :). Now to contribute a little, this is the way I write my functions if I am going to re-use code. If you will never use a function/code again, I see no harm in just including it in the binding as `$(window).on("resize", function(){});` I think this is a matter of preference and syntactic sugar.

Comment: I completely agree with @HanletEscaño!

Comment: this will help you to manage code efficiently, not forget to wrap with self executed function  to avoid outside world attackers.

Comment: Good, there's a nice point. Well, i liked this way of writing because i can name every function and separate declaring and calling, which seems easier (at least for me) to track errors and allows me to collapse more efficiently on Sublime Text 2

Comment: @Manivannan did you mean `(function(){ ... })();`? And the main point: can this cause problems?

Comment: Yes to self executive function, existing way of ur coding wouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: @Manivannan Good, thanks! Post an answer, and i'll set it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this won't harm any of the functionality and will help you maintain code efficiently. Note: wrap all off your code with self executive function which help you to prevent your code distribution from outside world.

Advantage of using this structure:
1)Readable 2)methods can be reused 3)easy to maintain

Comment: The note is not relevant to the question and needs further explanation of you really want to explain why you should do it

Comment: When I mentioned further explanation, I was talking about the unrelated comment about the self executing function

Comment: @ last statement, he added concerns that `if this method does affect the application in any sort of situation`. that's where i recommenced to use self executing function to avoid such a situation.

Answer (score 4):

The only way this could disturb existing code is if you had local variables with the same name as the functions.

The above is very unlikely, so go ahead and use whatever makes the code most readable. If your handler is just a few lines, I usually just use the inline anonymous function. For bigger handlers, it helps me to see the flow of the code without having to dig through/skip handlers